Bottlerocket Nodegroup do not start container from snapshot
I create a bottlerocket Nodegroup in my EKS cluster. All accoring to the tutorial on
https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/containers/reduce-container-startup-time-on-amazon-eks-with-bottlerocket-data-volume/
Everything looks, good, the snapshot was created without any error so I assume the container was pulled successful. But after adding a job to the cluster and autoscale nodes from bottlerocket nodegroup to 1, the "preloaded" container is ignored and the pod/eks/node start to fetch it from ECR with ignoring the snapshot.
The launch template for my nodegroup has ad volume:
EBS /dev/xvdb   snap-018730e53de5b61bf  225 gp2
The launch template do not show any other volume.
Image pull policy is "IfNotPresent" so it will first use local container.
Maybe someone has an idea why the pre-fetched container is not recognized by starting the EC2 / nodegroup?  Is bottlerocket inside a cluster not possible?
